# Display WCF content to listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I have a WCF Service Contract that is intended to send a string from the clipboard over TCP network and be received and displayed by winform listbox, I have managed to get both winforms connected, however I am having trouble getting the URL to display in the listbox.

### app.config

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <netPeerTcpBinding>
    <binding name ="NewBinding0">
      <security mode ="None" />
      <resolver mode ="Pnrp" />
    </binding>
  </netPeerTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <remove contract="IMetadataExchange" name="sb" />
  <endpoint address="net.p2p://URLService" binding="netPeerTcpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0" contract="WCFWinForm.IApplicationService"
            name="Client" />
</client>
<services>
  <service name="WCFWinForm.ApplicationService">
    <endpoint address="net.p2p://URLService" binding="netPeerTcpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0" contract="WCFWinForm.IApplicationService" />
  </service>
</services>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

### IApplicationService.cs

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IApplicationService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void GetURL();
}
```

### ApplicationService.cs

```
        public class ApplicationService : IApplicationService
        {
        public void GetURL()
            {
                var addCopy = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);
                WCF.listURL.Items.AddRange(addCopy.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
            }
        }
```

### WCF.cs (Winform)

```
    public static void WCF_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Establish connection with Service
        ServiceHost svc = new ServiceHost(typeof(ApplicationService));
        svc.Credentials.Peer.MeshPassword = "hehe";
        svc.Open();

        //Both Server and Client binding should match
        NetPeerTcpBinding np2p = new NetPeerTcpBinding();

        np2p.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
    }

    private void btnSendURL_MouseClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ApplicationService url = new ApplicationService();
        url.GetURL();
    }
```

You may notice in ApplicationService.cs I use WCF.listURL, this is because I don't know how to properly call the Form listbox; listURL inside ApplicationService.

Comment: The WinForm application should call the the service, the service should return the *data*, and then the WinForm should take the data and bind it to the control.  The service itself should know nothing about the client other than it requested an operation (method) to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, the service should know nothing about the client other than it requested data or some other operation to be performed.  I would recommend rewriting the service to return the data only, and have the client application bind that data to the `ListBox`.  However, you'll need to remove the `IsOneWay` attribute.  Something like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IApplicationService
{

    [OperationContract]
    string GetURL();
}
```

In the above code the one way attribute is removed, and the method returns a `string`.  I've used a `string` instead of array of `string` - the client can determine what to do with the data (split or not, reformat it, etc).

```
public class ApplicationService : IApplicationService
{

    public string GetURL()
    {

        return Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);
    }
}
```

The implementation simply returns the string of text from the clipboard.

```
private void btnSendURL_MouseClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ApplicationService url = new ApplicationService();
    string data = url.GetURL();

    listBox1.Items.AddRange(addCopy.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
}
```

Finally, the application will call the service method and get the returned data.  It will then add the data to the `ListBox` (named `listBox1` in the example).  Now you have decoupled your WCF service from your client, as it should be.

Comment: Hm I see what you mean. I tried this but it gets rid of my P2P WCF form connection and still doesn't add content to the listbox for some reason.

Comment: It shouldn't get rid of the connection.  How are you adding the connections?  You also might want to edit your question to include the relevant config files.

Comment: ok, I have updated with more information. Maybe you can better understand what I'm trying to do now... lol.